# SVN DAV only lists parent directory via HTTP

Tags: svn, webdav

I'm configuring SVN DAV via Apache2 using the following configuration:

```
<Location /svn/> 
     DAV svn 
     SVNParentPath C:\svn_repository 
     SVNListParentPath on
     Allow from all
     SVNAutoVersioning Off
</Location>
```

(PS: I already tried changing "Location /svn/" to "Location /svn" as suggested on other answers)

When I access {http://localhost/svn/project-name/} via HTTP or a WebDAV client (NetDrive for instance), it lists all the files for this project.

But when I access {http://localhost/svn/} via a WebDAV client, it doesn't show the list of repositories. Even though it does via HTTP.

Any hints?

Comment: What's the full config of the Apache vhost?  What are you seeing instead of the repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see a list of all repositories in a web browser pointing at:

```
http://localhost/svn/
```

If so, with this kind of setup I think it's normal behaviour to have to specify a specific repository. E.g.:

```
http://localhost/svn/myrepository
```

in your SVN client (TortoiseSVN for example).